# What is the exact difference between the scriptlet tags <%= some code %> and <# some code %>?

Tags: java, jsp

What is the exact difference between the scriptlet tags `<%= some code %>` and `<# some code %>`?

Comment: I removed the C# tag since this makes no sense. It's also not "java script", but officially "JSP scriptlet". Which is by the way a bad practice in real world. It's useful for one-page-appls and quick prototyping, but for anything beyond that you'd like to grab taglibs/EL/Javaclasses instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> its some what related to JSP too
>
> it can be used to print or display the value

```
Example:
In Jsp
<%String str=Response.getParameter(Field Name);%>
and if you want to access the value of "str" you should use
<%=str%>
```

Comment: can you please explain about second one ?

Comment: :-) fine

just confirm whether is it <# xxxx> or<@ xxxx>

Answer (score 0):

Both tags are related to asp.net and not to javascript. Both are aquivalent to

```
<% Response.Write("something") %>
```

but the second only on databound context like gridview, datalists and repeaters.